# How to handle Transport and Communication level Exception in WCF?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, exception

I know that we can use FaultException and FaultContract to catch these exception?

Is there any other way to (Except FaultException/FaultContract) catch specifically these two Exception (Transport and Communication)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft documentation, transport and communication errors are handled by the [CommunicationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.communicationexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

> Communication errors occur when a network is unavailable, a client
>   uses an incorrect address, or the service host is not listening for
>   incoming messages. Errors of this type are returned to the client as
>   CommunicationException or CommunicationException-derived classes.

The following provides a good overview of the three categories of WCF errors:

- Communication Errors
- Proxy/Channel Errors
- Application Errors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-error-handling